# mysql and php - Retrieving data from database based on user logged in

Tags: php, mysql, database

before I go ahead and attempt to create a website, I wanted to know if pulling a users content from a database depending on which user is logged in can be determined by a $_SESSION variable. So for example if I want all the messages for user 'example':

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'] // set when the user logs in
$username = $_SESSION['username']

$data = mysql_query("Select * from messagesTable where username = '$username'")
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
echo $row['message']
}
```

I wanted to know if this would be the right way to do something like this and also if its safe to return (personal) data based on a session variable.

I haven't got that much experience in either of these languages but I like to learn with experience, please tell me if it's not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is safe to return user data based on a `$_SESSION` variable if you are certain of its validity because you set it yourself in code.  It is *not safe* to return data based on a session variable that you get from `$_POST`.

You initially set

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

So unless you have verified with a password or otherwise that this user is who he claims to be, you should not use `$_POST['username']` to return other information.  If your login process (which we cannot see above) already verifies that `$_POST['username']` is valid, you can use it as a source to retrieve additional information.

You will need also to filter against SQL injection:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```

Comment: yea thanks sorry i just typed that out, my actual code includes all the other password checks and stuff lol

Comment: And also, unrelated to the question, you could look into mysqli or PDO, since the mysql functions are now deprecated. Hope it helps. =)

Answer (score 0):

that isn't standard and probably not safe since phpsession stay open even when a browser tab maybe not be open to the site since the cookie isn't eased until the browser is shutdown and also you could just send a post parameter to the site and get the info too so login scripts are a little more advanced, you could something like have a unique key that is generate upon logging in and when they leave the site using javascript delete the cookie something like that

Answer (score 0):

It wouldnt be the correct way to do it no.

May i suggest you go read the php/mysql docs and or a good book before attempting a website.

You also need to look into security(session hijacking, cross scripting, mysql attacks, form tokens, login systems, user roles/permissions).  Google search is your friend...

Comment: u gona actually say why its the wrong way to do it or just tell me to read a book lol

Comment: Cleary reading the docs or a book is not an option :P  Ive just given you 6/7 good reasons, or did you not read that either?

Comment: o right, i assumed there was more because you said 'also' lol

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
session_start();
    $username="";
    if($_SESSION['username']==true){
            $username=$_SESSION['username'];
            $conn=mysql_connect('localhost','user','passwd') or die("Unable   
                   to connect to database" .mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db('DBName') or die(mysql_error());
            $sql="SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE username='$username'";
            $retval=mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die("Could not perform query" 
              .mysql_error());
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($retval)){
                echo {$row['message']};
            }
            mysql_free_result($retval);
            mysql_close($conn);
    }
    else{
        return false;
        header("Location:login.php");
    }
?>
```